# How to enable GameCenter in macCatalyst without breaking Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, mac-catalyst

I'm developing an iOS game that uses GameCenter. I'm trying to create a macCatalyst build, to distribute the game for macOS as well. The API calls to GameKit on macOS were failing to communicate to `gamed`. I fixed that by enabling `Game Center` (`com.apple.developer.game-center`) in the `entitlements` file. However, after doing so, the iOS build fails to install on any device, giving me this error message:

```
Provisioning profile <xxx> doesn't include the com.apple.developer.game-center entitlement.
```

I tried disabling automatic code signing and creating my own provisioning profiles, after enabling the macOS flag under GameCenter, in my app ID page in developer.apple.com,

[image: GameCenter macOS]

But I still get the same error message.

If I try to re-enable automatic signing now, I get this other error message as well,

```
Automatic signing failed
Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at <https://feedbackassistant.apple.com> and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.
```

Why does the iOS provisioning profile need an entry for the Game Center entitlement? Isn't that entitlements file used for macOS only?

How can I include that entitlement in the iOS Provisioning Profile?

At the moment, every time I need to build on an iOS device, I have to delete the Game Center entry in the entitlements file (setting it to `NO` doesn't work), and I have to re-add it when testing on Mac.

Comment: I'm also currently trying to enable game center in mac catalyst app but it works only when I add com.apple.developer.game-center to entitlements. However when I do that I cannot resolve problems with provisioning profile and it shows an error "Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at <https://feedbackassistant.apple.com> and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.". Because of the problem with provisioning profile I can't send this to app store and if I remove the key from entitlements game center stops working. Did you found any solution to that?

Comment: No, I haven't found anything yet... :(

Comment: I was able to upload my app with com.apple.developer.game-center key in entitlements file to app store with Xcode 11.5 and game center works fine. However I did this while Xcode was still showing the same error about provisioning profile. I also found in release notes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_5_release_notes that this bug is a known issue so for now it seems that there is no way to remove the warning but at least it is possible to send working maccatalyst app with game center to app store.